# Appium Error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/Rotatable

Tags: appium

Getting **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/Rotatable** Error while instantiation of  instance of AndroidDriver. Earlier My project was running successfully but now continuously getting this error though there is no any change dependency

logs:-

```
FAILED: com.AppiumFramework.AppTest.testTestng
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/Rotatable
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at com.AppiumFramework.AppTest.testTestng(AppTest.java:18)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:677)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:221)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:962)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:194)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:806)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:601)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:433)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:427)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:387)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:330)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1256)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1176)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1099)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1067)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.Rotatable
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
```

I tried with
modifying dependency in Pom.xml file,
rebuild my maven project
Tried Maven Clean

Can anyone please help me if anyone face this issue and able to resolve it

Answer (score 3):

Update your appium-java-client maven dependency version to 8.3.0.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the below dependencies to your pom.xml file. It worked for me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And if you are using appium 2.0.0-beta.46 version, recommend to use the below dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.1</version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hello. I tried your solution but now it gives another error: https://app.screencast.com/pfaIwqGk4ZsRI